# Linear Regression algorithm works with one data-set but not on another, similar data-set. Why?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science

I created a linear regression algorithm following a tutorial and applied it to the data-set provided and it works fine. However the same algorithm does not work on another similar data-set. Can somebody tell me why this happens?

```
def computeCost(X, y, theta):
    inner = np.power(((X * theta.T) - y), 2)
    return np.sum(inner) / (2 * len(X))

def gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iters):
    temp = np.matrix(np.zeros(theta.shape))
    params = int(theta.ravel().shape[1])
    cost = np.zeros(iters)

    for i in range(iters):
        err = (X * theta.T) - y

        for j in range(params):
            term = np.multiply(err, X[:,j])
            temp[0, j] = theta[0, j] - ((alpha / len(X)) * np.sum(term))

        theta = temp
        cost[i] = computeCost(X, y, theta)

    return theta, cost

alpha = 0.01
iters = 1000

g, cost = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iters)  
print(g)
```

On running the algo through [this](https://github.com/Tan-Moy/ml_practice/blob/master/lr/data.csv) dataset I get the output as `matrix([[ nan,  nan]])` and the following errors:

```
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:2: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in power
  from ipykernel import kernelapp as app
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\__main__.py:11: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

However [this](https://github.com/Tan-Moy/ml_practice/blob/master/lr/data2.csv) data set works just fine and outputs `matrix([[-3.24140214, 1.1272942 ]])`

Both the datasets are similar, I have been over it many times but can't seem to figure out why it works on one dataset but not on other. Any help is welcome.

Edit: Thanks Mark_M for editing tips :-)

Comment: The reason you are getting downvotes is because you didn't take the time to isolate the problem and include code in your question. Nobody wants to wade through someone's repo and figure out what's wrong with their code. That's not what stack overflow is. You need to identify the problem and ask a specific question. Take a look here for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Mark_M Oh, I understand now. I will edit it. And what should I do about the dataets? Will a link be enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Much better question, btw]

It's hard to know exactly what's going on here, but basically your cost is going the wrong direction and spiraling out of control, which results in an overflow when you try to square the value.

I think in your case it boils down to your step size (alpha) being too big which can cause gradient descent to go the wrong way. You need to watch the cost in gradient descent and makes sure it's always going down, if it's not either something is broken or `alpha` is to large.

Personally, I would reevaluate the code and try to get rid of the loops. It's a matter of preference, but I find it easier to work with `X` and `Y` as column vectors. Here is a minimal example:

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
# this is your 'bad' data set from github
my_data = genfromtxt('testdata.csv', delimiter=',')

def computeCost(X, y, theta):
    inner = np.power(((X @ theta.T) - y), 2)
    return np.sum(inner) / (2 * len(X))

def gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iters):
    for i in range(iters):
        # you don't need the extra loop - this can be vectorize
        # making it much faster and simpler
        theta = theta - (alpha/len(X)) * np.sum((X @ theta.T - y) * X, axis=0)
        cost = computeCost(X, y, theta)
        if i % 10 == 0: # just look at cost every ten loops for debugging
            print(cost)
    return (theta, cost)

# notice small alpha value
alpha = 0.0001
iters = 100

# here x is columns
X = my_data[:, 0].reshape(-1,1)
ones = np.ones([X.shape[0], 1])
X = np.hstack([ones, X]) 

# theta is a row vector
theta = np.array([[1.0, 1.0]])

# y is a columns vector
y = my_data[:, 1].reshape(-1,1)

g, cost = gradientDescent(X, y, theta, alpha, iters)  
print(g, cost)
```

Another useful technique is to normalize your data before doing regression. This is especially useful when you have more than one feature you're trying to minimize.

As a side note - if you're step size is right you shouldn't get overflows no matter how many iterations you do because the cost will will decrease with every iteration and the rate of decrease will slow.

After 1000 iterations I arrived at a theta and cost of:

```
[[ 1.03533399  1.45914293]] 56.041973778
```

after 100:

```
[[ 1.01166889  1.45960806]] 56.0481988054
```

You can use this to look at the fit in an iPython notebook:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(my_data[:, 0].reshape(-1,1), y)
axes = plt.gca()
x_vals = np.array(axes.get_xlim())
y_vals = g[0][0] + g[0][1]* x_vals
plt.plot(x_vals, y_vals, '--')
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, you are right. I decreased the learning rate and it converged, giving `matrix([[ 0.05905856,  1.47833133]])`. I have just started ML and I find it awesome. And thanks for the useful advise about code optimizations, I will internalize them asap.